# Replace a payment method title for an external shipping service in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I am using Woocommerce and an external shipping service. I have a `$parameter['pay']` value that can have a string value  that can be "Cash" or "Terminal". I would like to replace those strings with a number like:

- "Cash" with 1
- "Terminal" with 2.

Here is my actual code where I would like to do that:

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'send_order_to_delivery');
function send_order_to_delivery( $order_id ){

    // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    $order_data = $order->get_data()

    $parameter['pay'] = $order_data['payment_method_title'];
}
```

So the `$parameter['pay']` should be 1 or 2.

I have tried this:

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'send_order_to_delivery');
function send_order_to_delivery( $order_id ){

    // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    $order_data = $order->get_data()

    $parameter['pay'] = $payment_method_code;

    $payment_method_code = $order_data['payment_method_title'];
    $cash = str_replace("Cash", "1", "$payment_method_code");
    $terminal = str_replace("Terminal", "2", "$payment_method_code");
}
```

But it throws an error.

How can I make that works? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the error comes from those 2 lines:

```
$cash = str_replace("Cash", "1", "$payment_method_code");
$terminal = str_replace("Terminal", "2", "$payment_method_code");
```

They should need to remove the `"` character from the variables to have this instead:

```
$cash = str_replace("Cash", "1", $payment_method_code);
$terminal = str_replace("Terminal", "2", $payment_method_code);
```

It will solves your error problem.

---

Now you could try the following, using `WC_Order` `get_payment_method_title()` method:

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'send_order_to_delivery');
function send_order_to_delivery( $order_id ){

    // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    $pay = array("Cash" => 1, "Terminal" => 2); 

    $param['pay'] = $pay[$order->get_payment_method_title()];
}
```

It could work.

Comment: Apparently I chose the wrong path. This code does not work. And all functions stop working.